# \nopagebreak and \penalty

Tags: page-breaking

What is the difference between `\nopagebreak` and `\penalty`? (Other than the obvious fact that their arguments are measured on different scales.) When should one use one, and when the other?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look at the definition of `\nopagebreak` (in `latex.ltx`):

```
\def\nopagebreak{\@testopt\@no@pgbk4}
\def\@no@pgbk #1[#2]{%
  \ifvmode
    \penalty #1\@getpen{#2}%
  \else
    \@bsphack
    \vadjust{\penalty #1\@getpen{#2}}%
    \@esphack
  \fi}
```

Discounting optional-argument crud, this basically says

> If in *vertical mode*, issue `\penalty\@getpen{#2}`, otherwise put
>   `\penalty\@getpen{#2}` in vertical mode after the current line of the current
>   paragraph.

What does `\@getpen` do?

```
\def\@getpen#1{\ifcase #1 \z@ \or \@lowpenalty\or
         \@medpenalty \or \@highpenalty
         \else \@M \fi}
```

This basically says

> If `#1==0`, return `0`, if `#1==1`, return `\@lowpenalty`, if `#1==2`,
>   return `\@medpenalty`, if `#1==3`, return `\@highpenalty`, if `#1==4`,
>   return `10000`.

How are `\@lowpenalty` etc. defined? Their definition is found in *the class file*:

```
\@lowpenalty   51
\@medpenalty  151
\@highpenalty 301
```

So, putting all together, the answer is

> `\penalty` is a low-level command which just inserts a *penalty* value
>   into the current output list, regardless of the current mode
>   (horizontal or vertical). `\nopagebreak` is a user-level command which
>   always adds a non-negative penalty *in vertical mode*. The concrete
>   value of the penalty is "abstracted" in five levels from *zero* to
>   *infinite*, and furthermore dependent on the *document class used*.

Answer (score 10):

The `\penalty` command is a TeX primitive that inserts a penalty node into the current list (e.g., a paragraph) while `\nopagebreak` is a high-level LaTeX command that inspects its suroundings (to some extent) and does different things depending on whether it is used in vertical or in horizontal mode.

If you are in the middle of a paragraph, then saying `\penalty 10000` is inserting a penalty that directs the linebreaking, but not one that affects the page breaking. In contrast `\nopagebreak` would insert more or less `\vadjust{\penalty 10000}` and it would do some additional magic to ensure that you don't end up with two spaces in that place.

So bottom line, **as a user you shouldn't use `\penalty` at all**, there are good reasons why LaTeX provides higher-level user commands. As a developer of a package, you may use penalty if you know what situation are in and of course using `\penalty` directly removes a tiny bit of overhead.