# longtable misplaced noalign

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable, r, sweave

## Question

Why am I getting multiple `misplaced \noalign` errors?

### Reproducible example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{Table test}

\begin{longtable}{llc}
\hline
 &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{All} \\ 
\hline
m & \rule{0pt}{1.7\normalbaselineskip}April  & $1$ \\
 & \nopagebreak July  & $1$ \\
 & \nopagebreak June  & $1$ \\
l & \rule{0pt}{1.7\normalbaselineskip}C  & $1$ \\
 & \nopagebreak F  & $1$ \\
 & \nopagebreak S  & $1$ \\
nums & \rule{0pt}{1.7\normalbaselineskip}28  & $2$ \\
 & \nopagebreak 62  & $1$ \\
\hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

### Desired output (through reproducible research toolchain---see below)

[image: desired output]

### Troubleshooting---Manual Tex Editing

It seems `misplaced /noalign` errors can be [vexing](http://www.tug.org/errors.html). My `\hline` is preceded by `\\`. Does the [comment](http://www.tug.org/errors.html) about `booktabs` apply here? If so, how do I fix it? Changing `\\` to `\\*` or `\tabularnewline` doesn't seem to help. As far as I can tell, this is not a `\centering` [issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109206/misplaced-noalign).

Removing `\nopagebreak` seems to make the errors go away but I don't think this is the right solution for me since the solution must work with long data tables in the context of a report using longtable. Please see below.

### Context

I believe that this is really a LaTeX question and not an R question but some context might help.

I am trying to generate a long report with multiple tables while adhering to principles of reproducible research by using R and the [tables](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/index.html) and [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) packages.

I would like to dynamically create a table with frequency counts of observations across multiple factored variables with some vertical space between each factored variable.

The [tables](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/index.html) package helps me do that using a nice formula interface, reminiscent of SAS proc tabulate. The `RowFactor()` function with the `suppressfirst=FALSE` and `spacing=X` arguments produces the necessary output provided I specify `nopagebreak = ""` instead of `nopagebreak = "\\nopagebreak "` or if I use a tabular environment instead of the longtable package. Unfortunatley, some of my tables are long and span page breaks. The tables package supports the LaTeX **longtable** package, as implemented on pages 26-28 of the tables [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf); but it doesn't seem to work with my data tables or with my minimal reproducible example.

### Reproducible R/Sweave code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\section{Table test}

<<test, echo=TRUE, results=tex>>=
options(width=80)
require(tables)
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(id=seq(1,3,1), 
                 m=sample(month.name, 3, replace=TRUE), 
                 l=sample(LETTERS, 3, replace=TRUE), 
                 nums=sample(1:100, 3, replace=TRUE))
latex(
  tabular(
    RowFactor(m, 
              suppressfirst=FALSE,
              ## default argument
              nopagebreak = "\\nopagebreak ",
              ## works if specify the following
              #nopagebreak = "",
              spacing=3)
    +RowFactor(l, 
              suppressfirst=FALSE,
              ## default argument
              nopagebreak = "\\nopagebreak ",
              ## works if specify the following
              #nopagebreak = "",
              spacing=3)
    +RowFactor(nums, 
               suppressfirst=FALSE,
               ## default argument
               nopagebreak = "\\nopagebreak ",
               ## works if specify the following
               #nopagebreak = "",
               spacing=3) ~1, data=df), 
  options=list(tabular="longtable")
)

@
\section{Session info}
<<sessionInfo>>=
sessionInfo()
@


\end{document}
```

Comment: What's `\nopagebreak` supposed to do?

Comment: @egreg In this context, `\nopagebreak` is intended to keep the table from breaking within table sections (e.g., ok to break between `l`, `m` and `nums` but not between the individual subrows. See LaTeX [help](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_110.html), this [question1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83350/nopagebreak-and-penalty) and this [question2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12034/how-to-make-longtable-respect-nopagebreak-in-the-beginning) which describe `\nopagebreak`.

Comment: It has no place where you put it.

Comment: @egreg, knowing that my small reproducible example is intended to demonstrate a problem with long data tables, and that the tex code was generated dynamically, what do you think about putting `nopagebreak` after each `\\ ` except at the end of each grouping of rows? This seems to compile correctly. Can you anticipate inherent problems with this approach? Ideally, the solution would be generalizable to the tool chain. If I suggest making a change to the `R tables` package regarding its handling of page breaks in longtables, I want to make the suggestion as robust as possible.

Comment: In order to avoid a page break at ``\\``, use ``\\*``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All `\nopagebreak`'s are undesired:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{Table test}

\begin{longtable}{llc}
\hline
 &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{All} \\ 
\hline
m & \rule{0pt}{1.7\normalbaselineskip}April  & $1$ \\
 &  July  & $1$ \\
 &  June  & $1$ \\
l & \rule{0pt}{1.7\normalbaselineskip}C  & $1$ \\
 &  F  & $1$ \\
 &  S  & $1$ \\
nums & \rule{0pt}{1.7\normalbaselineskip}28  & $2$ \\
 & 62  & $1$ \\
\hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my question, I note that removing `\nopagebreak` avoids the `misplaced \align` error message. I'm interested in your rationale. Why are all `\nopagebreak` undesired? Is it a technical reason? In my context of needing to present long tables of categorical data, I would prefer that the longtable breaks between row categories (e.g., `m`, `l`, or `nums`) but not between the sub-rows.

Comment: @penguinv22 saying `undesired` is just a polite way of saying they are a syntax error that can do nothing but generate an error in the position used. You used them in the middle column so I can't really guess the intended meaning as there is no possibility of page breaks being considered in the middle of the row. If you want to prevent page breaking between rows use `\\*` rather than `\\ ` You can use `\nopagebreak` but it has to be at the start of the row `\\\nopagebreak` is equivalent to `\\*`

Answer (score 43):

This isn't the answer to the original post, but I came here Googling for "Longtable misplaced noalign" so my eventual solution might be useful for someone.

In my case I needed a `\\` *after* the `\caption` and `\label`. This seems incredibly counterintuitive to me so if anyone can explain why or tell me where this is documented I'd be grateful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
% Uncomment the \\ on the next line and the misplaced \noalign disappears!
\caption{Captions should appear on top of tables}\label{tbl:table}%\\
    \toprule
                  & foo \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    bar           & 1 \\
    baz           & 2 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't tell you why that works but I had the same problem and this worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Same here, if someone has an explanation for that would be cool

Comment: Thanks for adding that;  anyone for an explanation?

Comment: The explanation is that the longtable package re-defines the `\caption` command insert the caption in a row. Since the caption is now a table row, it also needs to end like a table row: With \\.

The [documentation says:](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf)

The `\caption{...}` command is essentially equivalent to
`\multicolumn{n}{c}{\parbox{\LTcapwidth}{...}}`
where n is the number of columns of the table.

Comment: woa thanks so much, this works perfectly for me.

Comment: Classic SO - this should be the answer!!